How to solve 'PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer' in springboot?
I have been trying to upgrade my springboot application to Java 21 (the previous one was Java 17) and gradle version to 8.7. My spring boot version was '2.5.4' and now I have changed to '3.1.11' Now, when I try to run my application the following error appear:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:427) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:778) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at com.veiculos.bff.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:14) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.config.FF4JConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5a07e868]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:745) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:678) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1639) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
2024-06-18 17:07:48.483 WARN  [api--veiculos,-,-,-] 3304 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               .handleRunFailur : Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.config.FF4JConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5a07e868]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:745) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:678) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1639) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1314) ~[spring-context-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:878) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:866) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:853) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:792) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.11.jar:3.1.11]
    at com.veiculos.bff.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:14) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

My build.gradle file:
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    jacoco
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "7.4.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.11"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("org.sonarqube") version "3.3"
    id("info.solidsoft.pitest") version "1.7.4"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.23"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.5.4")
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:4.0.0.2929")
    }
}
pitest {
    setProperty("junit5PluginVersion", "0.12")
    setProperty("testPlugin", "junit5")
    setProperty("targetClasses", listOf("com.veiculos.bff.*"))
    setProperty("outputFormats", listOf("HTML"))
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("build/generated/src/main/java")
        }
    }
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated")
    packageName.set("com.veiculos.bff.controller.openapi")
    apiPackage.set("com.veiculos.bff.controller.openapi.api")
    modelPackage.set("com.veiculos.bff.controller.openapi.model")
        skipOverwrite.set(false)

    configOptions.set(
        mapOf(
            Pair("interfaceOnly", "true"),
            Pair("skipDefaultInterface", "true"),
            Pair("identifierNamingConvention", "snake_case"),
            Pair(
                "additionalModelTypeAnnotations",
                "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)"
            ),
            Pair("useJakartaEe", "true"),
            Pair("useSpringBoot3", "true")

        )
    )

}


group = "com.veiculos.bff"
version = "1.1.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["log4j2.version"] = "2.15.0"
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.1"
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")


    // Oauth2
    implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.5.1.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:5.6.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.6.1")


    //Servidor local redis
    implementation("it.ozimov:embedded-redis:0.7.1")


    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap")
    implementation("org.zalando:logbook-spring-boot-starter:3.7.2")
    implementation("org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.7")
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime-jvm:0.3.2")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.12.4")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.12.4")
    implementation("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot3:2.2.0")
    implementation("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-timelimiter:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.17.0")
    implementation("org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.6")


    kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final")



    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.11.2")
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.2.0"); testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    kaptTest("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.6.0")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:2.1.21")

    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.5.0")
    implementation("jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.1.0-M2")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-project-jakarta:2.2.21")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.21")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.19")

    implementation("org.jeasy:easy-random-core:5.0.0")
    testImplementation("org.jeasy:easy-random-core:5.0.0")

    //AWS
    implementation("com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-jdbc:1.0.12")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:1.12.692")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.12.692")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:1.12.692")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.12.493")

    //Feature-server
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:3.0.2")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.26")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:2.26")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:3.0.2")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1")
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:3.1.7")
    implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.3.1")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.11"
}

tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
            exclude(
                "**/configuration/**",
                "**/data/**",
                "**/enum/**",
                "**/mapper/**",
                "**/openapi/**",
                "**/exception/**",
                "**/factory/**",
                "**/context/**",
                "**/Application.*"
            )
        }
    )
}
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco")
        property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPath", "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml")
        property("sonar.inclusions", "**/src/main/kotlin/**/*")
        property(
            "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "" +
                    "**/configuration/**," +
                    "**/data/**," +
                    "**/enum/**," +
                    "**/mapper/**," +
                    "**/openapi/**," +
                    "**/exception/**," +
                    "**/factory/**," +
                    "**/context/**," +
                    "**/util/**," +
                    "**/Application.*"
        )
    }
}

tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "21"
    }
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy(tasks.getByName("jacocoTestReport"))
}

tasks.register<Zip>("zip") {
    archiveFileName.set("${project.rootProject.name}-${project.rootProject.version}.zip")
    destinationDirectory.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("${project.buildDir}/distributions"))
    from(layout.buildDirectory.dir("${project.buildDir}/libs")) {
        exclude("*-plain.jar")
    }
}

tasks.compileKotlin {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "21"
}
tasks.compileTestKotlin {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "21"
}

project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java).configureEach {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "21"
}

My SecurityConfig file:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf { obj: CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity> -> obj.disable() }
            .cors { obj: CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity> -> obj.disable() }
            .authorizeHttpRequests(Customizer { authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            })
            .sessionManagement { httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer: SessionManagementConfigurer<HttpSecurity?> ->
                httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(
                    SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
                )
            }
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurer(): WebMvcConfigurer {
        return object : WebMvcConfigurer {
            override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*")
            }
        }
    }
}

Do you guys have any idea how to solve it?
I tried to restart my intelliJ and invalidate cache, I also tried to update the dependencies version.

Mixing incompatible versions. You are mixing Spring Boot 3.1.11 and 2.5.4. That isn't going to work. Remove the buildscript part of the build file. Not sure if all the other dependencies are compatible with Spring Boot 3 (I doubt it) so you need to find the correct ones.

Do you know how I can find the correct ones? Is there a place where I can check it?

Check the docs but looking at your deps remove the jakarta.servlet-api and spring-web those are already included otherwise. You are also mixing versions of Jersey, remove the version numbers (spring boot will manage those)., the same for your micrometer dependencies. For the oauth server use the starter instead of individual dependencies.

unfortunately it is still not working :( Same error

Looking at this FF4JConfiguration uses incompatible classes.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet

Many class définitions have changed from javax to jakarta.
Also, just use Boot dependency management and define a version only when it is not defined there (directly or transitively). If you override managed versions, it is very likely that you'll run into compatibilty issues.
It will probably not be your last surprise. Look at migration guides.
